# Numpy append in a for loop using zip

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, zip

I have two different lists containing respectively some `x` and `z` values. From these two I need to take only some values and distribute `x` and `z` over to different rows.

So far I tried this:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 20]
z = [3, 5, 6, 9, 20, 25]

for x_val, z_val in zip(x, z):
    if x_val > 6 and z_val > 6:
        a = np.append(x_val, z_val)
```

From which I would expect `10, 15, 20` for the `x` and `9, 20, 25` for `z` but I only get the last values (20 and 25) on the same row.

```
a = [20, 25]
```

Comment: you overwrite `a` in every iteration

Comment: Why would you be using numpy in this?

Comment: @roganjosh because I have been asked to work only with array

Comment: @luigigi yeah, and how can I avoid that?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the requirement. "array" commonly reads as `np.array` in Python but is generally equivalent to our lists and people commonly get the two confused if they're from other languages. `np.append` will do a _full copy_ of the entire array on `append`, so it's grossly inefficient to build arrays like that. You should append to lists and then convert to an array at the end

Comment: What about `a = np.array(x+z)` then `a[a>6]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not 100% clear on your expected output (perhaps update the question to include). I've given a few different options below:

Option 1, using `numpy`:

```
a = np.array(x+z)
result = list(zip(*a[a>6].reshape(2, -1)))
```

Output:

```
[(10, 9), (15, 20), (20, 25)]
```

Option 2, if you'd rather not use numpy, you can do:

```
result = [(x_, z_) for x_, z_ in zip(x, z) if all([x_>6, z_>6])]
```

Output:

```
[(10, 9), (15, 20), (20, 25)]
```

Option 3, another output format can be done as:

```
result = list(zip(*[(x_, z_) for x_, z_ in zip(x, z) if all([x_>6, z_>6])]))
```

Output:

```
[(10, 15, 20), (9, 20, 25)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You always overwrite your array with last pair in line

```
a = np.append(x_val, z_val)
```

Create a array at the beginning, before for loop and then append to it in above line.

So complete working code (without numpy as it is not needed for simple arrays) is

```
x = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 20]
z = [3, 5, 6, 9, 20, 25]

a = []
for x_val, z_val in zip(x, z):
    if x_val > 6 and z_val > 6:
        a.append((x_val, z_val))
```